# windows cmd and powershell and macos,linux terminal

Tags: powershell

can someone explain to me the differences between windows cmd and powershell?
from what I can see powershell supports similar syntax to macOS terminal and Linux shell...
so is it better to use powershell in order to learn only one shell syntax that I can use across all three operating software? and why windows support those two different types of shells?
thank you

Comment: Powershell has the strong advantage that it's object-based, not text-based. Also it brings the full power of the .NET framework. And Powershell Core (Powershell v6+) runs on all these platforms even. You can easily find all this information through a simple google search, look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7) for example

Answer (score 2):

CMD is just the built in shell in windows, from an older time. PowerShell is a full turing-complete language that can do many more things.

You're absolutely right that it works across multiple platforms as well. At some point, Windows decided to move PowerShell to open-source, and make things cross-platform. This started a bit before PowerShell 7, but it's really production ready with PowerShell 7 I'd say.

I would definitely sink more time into PowerShell, as most CMD commands work there anyway, but there's probably some level of opinion there as well.

[Here's a good comparison](https://www.educba.com/powershell-vs-command-prompt/)